# modal form does not restore after minimize with 2 ui threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

The problem is that i have some kind of splash screen which shows loading animation.
I have special manager that show and hide it.

```
class Manager
 {
   private Form CurForm;
    Thread curt;

    private Manager()
    {
        curt= new Thread(start);
        curt.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        curt.IsBackground = true;
        curt.Start();
    }

    void start()
    {
        CurForm = new Animation();
        Application.Run(CurForm);
    }


    public static readonly Manager Active = new Manager();

    public static void Show()
    {
        if (Active.CurForm != null)
        {
            Active.CurForm.Invoke(new Action(() => { Active.CurForm.Show(); }));
        }
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        if (Active.CurForm != null)
        {
            Active.CurForm.Invoke(new Action(() => { Active.CurForm.Hide(); }));
        }
    }
}
```

I open some modal form (ShowDialog). This modal form doesn't show in taskbar.

I easily can minimise it and after clicking on main form on task bar it show that modal form on top.

But when I show this loading animation while it's loading all necessary data.

some kind like that (of course it is just a sample to test it work, and in real app it tooks  much time to load all data and form with lots of controls)

```
    public modal()
    {
        Manager.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Manager.Hide();
    }
```

And when i'm trying to minimise and restore it like i said above it doesn't restore my modal form and just show my main not available form. And more than that it works in some cases but in some not.

Does anybody know why it is happens or how to fix it?

Comment: Your **curt** thread doesn't do anything? This is all running on the main thread?

Comment: curt it is splash screen thread. I need to create some  separate thread to animate my splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is strange but when i modify like this, everything seems  to work normal.

I just kill separate ui thread.

```
public class MyApplicationContext:ApplicationContext
{
    public Form CurForm;

    ManualResetEvent ready = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public MyApplicationContext()
    {
        CurForm=new Animation();
        CurForm.Show();
    }
}

class Manager
{
    private MyApplicationContext CurContext;

    Thread curt;


    void start()
    {
        try
        {
            CurContext = new MyApplicationContext();
            Application.Run(CurContext);
        }
        catch
        {
            CurContext.CurForm.Close(); 
        }
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        curt = new Thread(start);
        curt.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        curt.IsBackground = true;
        curt.Start(); 
    }

    public static Manager Active
    {
        get
        {
            if (active == null)
            {
                active = new Manager();

            }
            return active;
        }
    }

    private static Manager active;

    public static void Show()
    {
        Active.Init();           
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        Active.curt.Abort();                        
    }
```